# What's the meaning of this in Eclipse: "Path for project must have only one segment."

Tags: android, eclipse

There is a problem in Eclipse when I run my Android application:

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration (1)".
>   Path for project must have only one segment.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You must specify project name in settings (see the image) and change android SDK suitable with your version.

Go to Run>Run Configuration

It will bring up the following screen. 
You can enter the project name manually or click browse and select the project to add the name automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

You can solve it by the following steps:

Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings:

1. select "Launching New_configuration"
2. Delete
3. OK

Comment: +1 for answer. And google if you are listening, this should not happen. I just created a new project, and it comes ready broken.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have forgotten to give name of the project.I did face the same in Eclipse Kepler .When I gave project name the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with VSCode in the launch.json for debugging a Java Project.
And the problem was that I had a "/" (slash) in the "pojectName" property of debug config. once I removed the "/" from projectName it got resolved

Answer (score 0):

**In Eclipse** : close all the project then Goto File -> Exit

Then again start eclipse, select the project/maven project from directory which you want to load. Then goto eclipse import select the project from directory again if it's not loaded ... this time you won't getting this error.

I too was getting this error for Maven project and this approach worked for me.