# Running Android Application in Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, configuration, android-emulator

I am facing Problem while running/debugging android application I am getting error like An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
Path for project must have only one segment. why am I getting this error????

Comment: You can find the answer in the stack over flow which is already mentioned  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357111/whats-the-meaning-of-this-in-eclipse-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segm?rq=1  Please check before asking the questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you out!

Please enter a name and project in your run configuration

Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings:

> 1. select "Launching New_configuration"
> 2. Delete
> 3. OK