# Python: 'Path for project must have only one segment'

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

I used to develop openerp on windows environment, currently I work on linux. 
I have successfully installed jdk, postgres server, openerp, python and identifying the python interpreter on eclipse. 
In eclipse  when I add new_configurations for the python run the following exception is shown
        ***Path for project must have only one segment*.**
As shown in the following image:- [image]

Any eclipse version I downloaded it I got the same exception.  So I’d be so thankful to you if you hint me about the cause of this problem and how can I overcome it.

I use:-
- Ubuntu 12.04.
-  Python 2.7.
- java 1.7
-  postgresql-9.3
- eclipse Luna M6  Release (4.4.0M6)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error went away for me after upgrading to PyDev 3.9. Now Eclipse crashes when I try to debug my project, but that's a whole different problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to specify a project name, and as you can see on your image, you forgot to do that.

The error is not that self describing but if you fill out that field the error should be resolved.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357111/whats-the-meaning-of-this-in-eclipse-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segm), it's tagged Android but it's not really a language specific error.

Comment: I thought like that, but when I press OK to the message and try to add the project name the field itself is not editable, even going from tab to tab isn't applicable.The windown exactly like an picture does not allow me to write any thing or move from tab to tab.

Comment: @HebatuAllahFahmy really? Can you show a screenshot of when the field is not editable?

Comment: yes it is not editable. When I used eclipse Keleper, Juno and galileo the same error appeared but the screen of configuration doesn't appear at all. Eclipse Luna can get the configuration screen with the appearance of the exception but it make it non adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing exactly the same behaviour, but only since applying the latest Kepler updates (to Build  20140224-0627).  In my case, it's on a previously working Windows 7 platform, so it looks more like an Eclipse bug than anything else.