# Eclipse IvyDE managed libraries not exported into runnable JAR file

Tags: eclipse, class, jar, ivy, ivyde

#### The problem

So far, Eclipse has exported IvyDE managed libraries into a runnable JAR file, but I'm not sure why it has stopped working recently.

What's wrong? How can I fix the issue?

#### ivy.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation= "http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
  <info organisation="com.example" module="eclipse-ivyde-export-issue" />
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.json" name="json" rev="20220320"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

#### Steps for reproducing the issue

1. Clone [the project](https://github.com/haba713/eclipse-ivyde-export-issue):

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:haba713/eclipse-ivyde-export-issue.git
   ```
2. Import the cloned project into Eclipse workspace.
3. Right-click the class `src/com.example/Main.java` in the project tree and
   choose Run as → Java Application. See the output: `{"key":"value"}`.
4. Right-click the project and choose Export → Java → Runnable JAR file.
5. Choose the launch configuration for the class `com.example.Main` and
   Library handling: [x] Extract required libraries into generated JAR. Click
   Finish.
6. Try to run the generated JAR file:

   ```
   $ java -jar eclipse-ivyde-export-issue.jar
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
     at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:8)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
     ... 1 more
   ```

#### Environment

- Eclipse 2022-06 M2 (4.24.0 M2)
- IvyDE 2.2.0.final-201311091524-RELEASE
- OpenJDK 17.0.3+7-Debian-1deb11u1
- Debian GNU/Linux 11 (Bullseye)

#### Eclipse 2020-06 with OpenJDK 8 works fine

I tested the same project with Eclipse 2020-06 and OpenJDK 8. JAR export gives a warning "This operation repacks referenced libraries" and IvyDE managed classes are included into the generated JAR file.

(The question was posted also to [Eclipse Community Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1852851/).)

Comment: Does the project have `Ivy nature` applied? Try adding it and refreshing ivy. Eclipse classpath might be not correctly set.

Comment: The project has "Ivy nature". Maybe it was automatically added when IvyDE Managed Dependencies was added to Java Build Path → Libraries.

Comment: Try adding libraries on `<project> -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357162/2834978

Comment: @LMC, thanks for helping! However, there's no Deployment Assembly in the project properties because this is Java Project (not Dynamic Web Project). And yes, the project name is in the run configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Workaround

I think that this is a JDT or IvyDE bug. Workaround is to use JRE System Library 1.8 instead of 17. See [the note at the end of README](https://github.com/haba713/eclipse-ivyde-export-issue#workaround-use-jre-system-library-18-instead) for more information.

The chosen Launch configuration must have JDK 1.8 as a runtime environment.